# how can I use component only in dev?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have some translation components that I would like to use only in the development environment. The idea is that the component does not get compiled when the project builds.

How can I achieve that in AngularDart 5?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you'd like your component to be loaded/not loaded, there are different strategies you can take. My preferred one usually is to have two entry-points for your application, i.e. `web/main.dart`, and `web/main.dev.dart`, and have the latter be the only one that imports/uses/loads the component in question.

For example, you could have the following definition in `lib/translation.dart`:

```
void Function() loadTranslationComponent = () {};
```

And in `web/main.dev.dart`:

```
import 'package:name/translation.dart';

void main() {
  loadTranslationComponent = () {
    // Code to initialize and use only in development mode.
  };
}
```